# Paragraph text using img space

Tags: html, css, image, web

I'm trying to make the whole thing clickable so I wrapped the image and paragraph inside an anchor tag. I gave the anchor tag a padding of 40px around and gave the img tag a right margin of around 30. Both of them have a display property of inline-block. The problem is it doesn't show like the one on the image(attached). How do I fix this? I'm not that good at CSS and HTML yet. Thanks.

```
<div class="col-md-3">
<a href="./"><img src="_assets_/images/icon-meeting.png" alt="meeting minutes and agendas"><p>Meeting Minutes &amp; Agendas</p></a>
</div><!-- /.col-md-3 -->
<div class="col-md-3">
<a href="./"><img src="_assets_/images/icon-bills.png" alt="pay bills online"><p>Pay Bills Online</p></a>
</div><!-- /.col-md-3 -->
<div class="col-md-3">
<a href="./"><img src="_assets_/images/icon-document.png" alt="form &amp; document center"><p>Form &amp; Document Center</p></a>
</div><!-- /.col-md-3 -->
<div class="col-md-3">
<a href="./"><img src="_assets_/images/icon-questions.png" alt="frequently asked questions"><p>Frequently Asked Questions</p></a>
</div><!-- /.col-md-3 -->
```

My CSS is:

```
#panel p {font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;color: #fff;font-size: 18px;display: inline-block;margin: 0}
#panel img {width: 45px;margin-right: 25px;display: inline-block}
#panel a {background-color: #1b4952;display: block;border-radius: 10px;text-decoration: none}
```

[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUz1g.jpg)

[What I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGq4p.jpg)

Comment: Can you please share the related CSS or create a working example using [SOs Code Blocks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).

Comment: Ok. So you want "<IMG>Text" and not something like "<IMG><Line Break>Text" - right? If so - first, get rid of the <p> tags as that starts a new paragraph and you want it all together. Second, you may want to consider creating a small table with 1 row and 2 columns to display the information. That would keep it all together. Third, you might consider making all of it a single image via GD. That would keep it all together also. Just some thoughts. :-)

Comment: Hi. I just edited my post and added the CSS I have. Thanks!

Comment: Can you show me how to do that, please? Thanks

Comment: I see ZgrKARALAR has already posted an answer. If that works - go for it! :-) If not - let me know. :-)

Comment: @MarkManning As you know not easy sometimes give a answer part of code :)  because need more details as again you know :) But i try something to help to new user :)

Comment: @ZgrKARALAR : True! :-) I marked your answer up because I think it is the right answer. :-)

Comment: @Chad : A table is really simple but if you are using bootstrap ZgrKARALAR's answer is probably better. Table example: <table><tr><td><a href...><img...></a></td></td>[TEXT]</td></tr></table>. That is the basic way to do a table. You can also use the NOWRAP option on the TD command to keep the text from wrapping. Use the BORDER='0' on the TABLE command to remove borders.

Comment: Thank you for the help, guys! I'll try using the table, too.

Answer (score 1):

I guest you use bootstrap :)

About that you can make it using row. I just simple edit your code check and try it i hope it's help you.

```
<div class="col-md-3">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <a href="./"><img src="_assets_/images/icon-meeting.png" alt="meeting minutes and agendas">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <p>Meeting Minutes &amp; Agendas</p></a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div><!-- /.col-md-3 -->
<div class="col-md-3">
   <div class="row"> 
   <div class="col-md-6">
<a href="./">
     <img src="_assets_/images/icon-bills.png" alt="pay bills online">
      <div class="col-md-6">
     <p>Pay Bills Online</p></a>
</div> 
     </div>
     </div>
     </div>
     <!-- /.col-md-3 -->
<div class="col-md-3">
   <div class="row"> 
   <div class="col-md-6">
<a href="./">
     <img src="_assets_/images/icon-document.png" alt="form &amp; document center">
     <div class="col-md-6">
     <p>Form &amp; Document Center</p></a>
  </div>
     </div>
     </div>
</div><!-- /.col-md-3 -->
<div class="col-md-3">
 <div class="row"> 
   <div class="col-md-6">
<a href="./"><img src="_assets_/images/icon-questions.png" alt="frequently asked questions">
  <div class="col-md-6"><p>Frequently Asked Questions</p></a>
    </div>
   </div>
   </div>
</div><!-- /.col-md-3 -->
```

More informations check [this](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html) page

Comment: Thank you!  I'm not sure if we're allowed to do that at work but I'll use it still. :)